# Method UseSqlServer not recognized in options when registering database under .NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.2#register-the-schoolcontext), the context can be added using the following syntax.

```
services.AddDbContext<Context>(
  options=>options.UseSqlServer("beep"));
```

It works in previous versions of Core 2.x and below. However, now that I try out Core 3.0 preview it seems that the method isn't present according to the intellisense. There's a bunch of `options.UseXxx`'s but nothing about databases or SQL.

Googling gave a number of hits like [this one](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7891) but all of them are from 2017 and seem to relate to an old issue in the initial versions of .NET Core, while info on the newest version seems not to be available.

I've check the [breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes) for .NET Core 3.0 but didn't recognize anything relevant there.

How do I register an SQL database in .NET Core 3.0?

Comment: A note, from 3.0 one need to grab the SqlClient nuget manually. And you might want to have a read about this new package: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-new-microsoftdatasqlclient/

Comment: Also, given the breaking changes you linked to is about **EF Core 3.0**, and not ".Net Core 3.0", you might need to clarify that in your question, which .Net Core and EF Core you use.

Comment: @LGSon Interesting point. While obviously understanding the distinction between A 3.0 and B 3.0, I expected the fauna of packages to be coordinated so that they support each other given that we let all the 3's play together. I haven't researched it thoroughly, so the following is merely a speculation. I wanted to knead Core 3 and discovered that I had to install new versions of "everything", gradually. What's your take on that? (NB. It's a hunch not a rant.)

Comment: I would say, given the logic in e.g. ".NET Framework", where one can run "EF 6" with "NET 4.8", means they doesn't need to be of the same version. And if, and one of them bumps its version it would all break...?

Comment: @LGSon I agree with your point of view. I suspect, thought, that it's exactly what happened in Core 3. I didn't get the old code to work because some things seemed to changed. But it **might** be my confusion and that I missed a small something. I've been working EF since many years so I recognize my bearings but one never knows. Thanks for the input, in any case.

Comment: Also note, with NET Core 3.0 itself, many packages that were included by default in 2.2 have been dropped, and needs to explicit be added as nuget's, and some are _implied_, which means they shouldn't be added manually at all, as they will automatically bump up with version updates.

Comment: Here's a start if you haven't read it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 8):

I have resolved this issue by running `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` on my Package Manager Console. Then Added `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` on top of my StartUp.cs file

Comment: I only have to add `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` and it works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

By adding

**using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;**

It worked for me. I was using Net 5 Console Application

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is with this [breaking change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#entity-framework-core-is-no-longer-part-of-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework):

> Starting in 3.0, the ASP.NET Core shared framework doesn't include EF Core or any EF Core data providers.

So you just need to add an explicit reference to the EF Core database provider you are using ([SQL Server](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/)) and the UseSqlServer extension method should become available again.

Comment: Are you saying that I should add `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` at the top of the file? I've done that but it's greyed out and the original issue remains. If you mean something else, please elaborate, preferably with a line or two showing the example. I'm totally lost.

Comment: I need to elaborate myself. I've tried installing [this version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/3.0.0-preview6.19304.10) but I get errors in the console about *Detected package downgrade*, which surprises me because I'm **upgrading** to 3.0.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted or why. Wasn't me, though and I'm upping you back to zero. Regardless - do you have anything wise in regard to my comments?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have added in the NuGet packages of

**Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore** as well as

**Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer**.

**Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer** has "UseSqlServer" so without this package, you can't use that method.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` then add using statement:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

to make sure the method accessible you can call it as a static method:

```
 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContext, connectionString);
```